# Simultaneously get multiple resources by ID

Tags: google-docs-api

There exists a DocsClient.get_resource_by_id function to get the document entry for a single ID.  Is there a similar way to obtain (in a single call) multiple document entries given multiple document IDs?

My application needs to efficiently download the content from multiple files for which I have the IDs.  I need to get the document entries to access the appropriate download URL (I could manually construct the URLs, but this is discouraged in the API docs).   It is also advantageous to have the document type and, in the case of spreadsheets, the document entry is required in order to access individual worksheets.

Overall I'm trying to reduce I/O waits, so if there's a way I can bundle the doc ID lookup, it will save me some I/O expense.

[Edit] Backporting AddQuery to gdata v2.0 (from Alain's solution):

```
client = DocsClient() 
# ...
request_feed = gdata.data.BatchFeed()
request_entry = gdata.data.BatchEntry()
request_entry.batch_id = gdata.data.BatchId(text=resource_id)
request_entry.batch_operation = gdata.data.BATCH_QUERY
request_feed.add_batch_entry(entry=request_entry, batch_id_string=resource_id, operation_string=gdata.data.BATCH_QUERY)
batch_url = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_FEED_URI + '/batch'
rsp = client.batch(request_feed, batch_url)
```

`rsp.entry` is a collection of BatchEntry objects, which appear to refer to the correct resources, but which differ from the entries I'd normally get via `client.get_resource_by_id()`.

My workaround is to convert `gdata.data.BatchEntry` objects into `gdata.docs.data.Resource` objects ilke thus:

```
entry = atom.core.parse(entry.to_string(), gdata.docs.data.Resource)
```

Comment: NOTE: batch queries don't currently work with two-legged oauth with user impersonation (where the client auth_token uses an admin requestor_id and "/default" in the batch entry query URLs is replaced by the impersonated user).  So this whole exercise is moot if you intend to lookup up items with different owners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#batching_resource_operations_into_a_single_request) to send multiple "GET" requests to the API using a single HTTP request.
Using the Python client library, you can use this code snippet to accomplish that:

```
def retrieve_resources(gd_client, ids):
  """Retrieve Documents List API Resources using a batch request.

  Args:
    gd_client: authorized gdata.docs.client.DocsClient instance.
    ids: Collection of resource id to retrieve.

  Returns:
    ResourceFeed containing the retrieved resources.
  """
  # Feed that holds the batch request entries.
  request_feed = gdata.docs.data.ResourceFeed()

  for resource_id in ids:
    # Entry that holds the batch request.
    request_entry = gdata.docs.data.Resource()
    self_link = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_SELF_LINK_TEMPLATE % resource_id
    request_entry.id = atom.data.Id(text=self_link)
    # Add the request entry to the batch feed.
    request_feed.AddQuery(entry=request_entry, batch_id_string=resource_id)

  # Submit the batch request to the server.
  batch_url = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_FEED_URI + '/batch'
  response_feed = gd_client.Post(request_feed, batch_url)

  # Check the batch request's status.
  for entry in response_feed.entry:
    print '%s: %s (%s)' % (entry.batch_id.text,
                           entry.batch_status.code,
                           entry.batch_status.reason)
  return response_feed
```

Make sure to sync to the latest version of the [project repository](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/checkout).

Comment: I may be restricted to gdata 2.0.x series, at least for the time being.  Is there a 2.0-compatible equivalent (looking through the python-2.0 client library docs now...)?